styling tabs in flowbite-react
 function Tab() {
  return (
    <>
    <Tabs aria-label="Default tabs" style="default">
        
      <Tabs.Item active title="Profils" icon={HiUserCircle}  className="bg-red-500">
        This is profiles
      </Tabs.Item>
      
      <Tabs.Item title="Dashboard" icon={MdDashboard}>
        This is Dashboard
      </Tabs.Item>
      
    </Tabs>
    <Button>Hello</Button>
    </>
  );
}

how to style tabs in flowbite-react
IN this code, className="bg-red-500" in Tabs.Item is not working, why?
And additonally, how to make each tab item customizable by adding height and weight?
I want to make each tab item and overall tab customizable!
